# How can I automatically re-scale a rectangular image after rotating with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In my app, users can take pictures vertically or horizontally, and may want to rotate the image after taking it. To solve this, we have a rotate feature in-app that they can use to modify the image.

The issue with this, is that, when rotating, the image could be cut-off on each side. (see pictures)

Before rotating:

[image: Before rotating]

After rotating:

[image: After rotating]

When paging, you can see the image stretching beyond its own screen:

[image: When paging, you can see the image stretching beyond its own screen]

Here is the code I have so far. The `modifier` is going to an `Image` composable in `ImageZoomView`.

```
val rotationAnim by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = viewModel.slides[page].rotation.value.toFloat(),
    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 200, easing = FastOutLinearInEasing)
)

Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    ImageZoomView(
        modifier = Modifier
            .rotate(rotationAnim)
            .weight(1f),
        bitmap = bmp,
        zoomable = viewModel.zoomable.value
    )
}
```

The `weight(1f)` part of the `Modifier` is automatically scaling the image when the page loads, but this never gets re-calculated when the rotation takes place.

Some things I've tried to no avail:

- Set the `weight` to a mutable state, and then overwrite it whenever `rotation` changes.
- Move `rotate` to the parent `Column`
- Skip the animation
- Loading with the rotation hard-coded to 90 also cuts off the edges exactly the same as the screenshots.